# How to use LinkedHashmap in Recyclerview to store the list in order and when scrolls back, must retrieve back those objects?

Tags: java, android

I'm have used asynctask to display the images of 100 URL using recyclerview from the the internet without using any third party libraries. When i'm scrolling the images, they flicker and the values like 1 to 100 those chnages and takes little time to fit the exact no. on the image view, I figured out it can be done using LinkedHashmap. But i dont know how to use it and where to use it? do i need to write a new separate code for it or do need to just change the data type of Array String URL's to LinkedHashmap ArrayList? My Question might be Unclear. Please Manage. Kindly Provide a relavant solution if possible.

Comment: What you tried please post here and mention the question on that.

Comment: I'm tyring to load multiple Url images, using Aysnctask and Recycler view.Whenever i scroll quickly those images seems to flicker. for eg. i'm displaying 1 to 100 images -> http://onethousandpaintings.com/imgs/numbers/number_1.png when u chnage the number the image changes with corresponding numbers.  On scrolling quickly the numbers keep on changing and takes little time to set on the exact position,So thought of using LinkedHashmap concept. But i dont know how to implement it. kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

I think linkedHashmap cannot be solve your problem ,it is reduce the usage of data consuming during download the image.so you can search any other way.

Comment: please clarify on your answer.

Comment: It avoid the multiple times of download the same image.